# Where is the best place to put contact information?

Tags: contact-us

Comparing the two designs below, is it better to put contact information below the map in the right column or below the images and description on the left?

## Contact information below the map:

[image]

## Contact information below the description:

[image]

Comment: A little more context would be helpful like what is the purpose of the site or the page and some wireframes would make it even better.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that it makes sense to group the location and contact information together. The information is logically related (information about where the place is and how to contact it) and the map serves as a conspicuous focal point that will draw the user's eye to that part of the page - the map shouts "look here for information about this location".